# Regex replacement for URI in vrl (vector.dev)

Tags: regex, vector-vrl

I need a regex that replaces the pieces of a URI that would create a high cardinality situation.

Basically if the segment of a URI contains any non `a-zA-Z` characters (other than `/`), replace it with an `*`

Example:

```
$ replace("/first/12ab34/B1a234/12B3a/1234/second/A789B-89d", r'(?i)[a-z]*\d+(?i)[a-z]*',"*")
```

results in: `"/first/**/**/**/*/second/*-*"`

That's close, but I need `"/first/*/*/*/*/second/*"`

Multiple replaces are acceptable. Any regex masters out there willing to help?
This is for vrl (vector.dev) written in Rust. VRL does not support look-around of any kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example data, you might use

```
(?i)[a-z]*\d[\da-z]*(?:-[\da-z]+)*
```

- `(?i)` Inline modifier for case insensitive
- `[a-z]*` Match optional chars a-z
- `\d` Match a single digit
- `[\da-z]*` Match optional digits or chars a-z
- `(?:-[\da-z]+)*` optionally repeat a `-` and 1+ times either a digit or a-z

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TkT3VE/1)

Comment: Finally settled on `(?i)[a-z.-]*\d[\da-z.-]*(?:-[\da-z.-]+)*`
Thank you! Big help

Answer (score 1):

Use

```rust
[^/\d]*\d[^/]*
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/wzjpD3/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```rust
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^/\d]*                  any character except: '/', digits (0-9) (0
                           or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^/]*                    any character except: '/' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Answer (score 0):

`[^/]*[^/a-zA-Z][^/]*`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NK02wE/1)

#### Explanation

- `[^/a-zA-Z]` - exactly one "non a-zA-Z characters (other than /)"
- `[^/]*` - zero or more characters that are not "/"

The middle part will guarantee that the path element has at least one "non a-zA-Z" character. The side parts will match everything up to the enclosing "/" (excluding). All three together will match the whole path element, which has at least one "non a-zA-Z" character in it.

#### More tests

```
$ replace("12ab34/first/B1:a234/12B3a/12_34//second/4931962a-4478-4151-b570-3329b9d29b1f/third_/-fourth", r'[^/]*[^/a-zA-Z][^/]*',"*")
"*/first/*/*/*//second/*/*/*"
```

- it will match path elements without leading/trailing slash
- `:` is matched as non a-zA-Z character
- empty path element `//` is not replaced
- it will match path elements with multiple non a-zA-Z character
- it will match path elements where the non a-zA-Z character is at the beginning/end